# Get the value of a field in a Webform in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-webform, drupal-hooks

I created a form with the "Webform" module. In this form I have one field of e-mail type. My question is: how can I get the value of this field when the user  submits the form?

I guess I should use the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) (or [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), if you prefer).

When You have `$form` argument from these hooks, You should set an array as value of `$form['#submit']` with name of your function in which you will catch your needed values.

Example:

```
$form['#submit'] = array('node_form_function_submit');
```

[...]

```
function node_form_function_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $form_state['values']; // your submitted form values
}
```

Comment: The structure of array is more or less like this:  $form_state['values']['e-mail'] = example@email.com                                                                                    This is correct? if this is correct, can I save the value into a variable?

Comment: @LTurcios Yup, that's right. You can take this value and set to whatever other variable you want.